# Toggle Img Source after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have an img and I have a javascript code to change the source of the img after 3 seconds, my problem is that, after changing the source and rendering the 3 images it doesn't show again the first pic, so I guess is not looping? could someone help me to solve this? thanks!

HTML

```html
<img id="graphics" src="images/graphic1.svg" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
(function() {     // function expression closure to contain variables
    var i = 0;
    var pics = [ "graphic1.svg", "graphic2.svg", "graphic3.svg" ];
    var el = document.getElementById('graphics');  // el doesn't change

    function toggle() {
        el.src = pics[i];           // set the image
        i = (i + 1) % pics.length;  // update the counter
    }

    setInterval(toggle, 3000);
})();             // invoke the function expression
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious problem in the code and running a quick test (just console logging the value of pics[i]) this seems to run fine. Might be another part of the code that's breaking?

Comment: Yeah, this jsfiddle seems to show src updating correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/zs12qdhx/

Comment: @GuyNesher Thanks pal, I solve that problem by adding "images/graphic1.svg" since they're inside a folder called images, working perfectly. but the real problem is, I have an initial source Which I consider the graphic1.svg it should change only to graphic2 and graphic3 but then get back to graphic1. right now, is running first the graphic1.svg image, then running the graphic1.svg, the graphic2 and graphic3 converting it in 4 steps. instead of just 3, you know what I mean?

Comment: @Eugenio , var i = 1; should fix that,
Right now, you are going from graphic1.svg to pics[0], which is also graphic1.svg, alternately you could put graphic1.svg last in your array so pics[0] is graphic2.svg

Comment: @user2267175 you were right:)! var i = 1 solved that:D!! awesome thankss!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop OK

I tested your code and the loop is OK.

[CodePen Test](http://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/MKZxeb/)

```
(function() { // function expression closure to contain variables
var i = 0;
var pics = ["http://placehold.it/200x100/f00/fff.png", "http://placehold.it/200x100/f0f/000.png", "http://placehold.it/200x100/333/999.png"];
var el = document.getElementById('graphics'); // el doesn't change
function toggle() {
    el.src = pics[i]; // set the image
    i = (i + 1) % pics.length; // update the counter
}
setInterval(toggle, 3000);
})(); // invoke the function expression
```

## Check Image Path

The problem can be the path to your images. You may need to append **images/** to the **src**.